# Python requests.post code limits results to 200. How to adjust code to get all 1000+ results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I can't seem to figure our where to adjust any data limit in the requests.post statement.  But there appears to be a 200 results limit in the output.  Not very comfortable writing advanced requests.post scripts and could use some help with this issue.

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://cares.myflfamilies.com/PublicSearch/Search?dcfSearchBox=Orange in Counties')
openFile = open('flData', 'wb')
for chunk in r.iter_content(100000):
    openFile.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a loop?

Comment: That's a restriction imposed by that specific website. Nothing to do with `requests`.

Comment: Many sites implement paging, you get a "next" link which retrieves the next *n* results and possibly a way to tweak the value of *n* within reasonable limits.

Comment: @ThatBird, can you please elaborate on your suggestion?  Where would I use a loop in the requests statement and how would that help me obtain all the results I'm looking for based on the criteria embedded in the requests statement?

Comment: @tripleee - what if the site doesn't provide a "next" link?  Any other options?

Comment: @blhsing - Is there a way to get around any restrictions this site is imposing?

Comment: If the site is fundamentally broken, all I can come up with is a brute-force search. Figure out a way to partition the result in (say) five sets which are each less than 200 records, perhaps by adding something to the query. Does the site allow you to seach by postal code, for example? (How many ZIP codes are there in Orange County?) Or by truncating a search term, like `lastname=a*` through `lastname=z*`

Comment: Never attribute to malice or stupidity that which is caused by legal reasons, which sublimely combine both. Make sure you are not violating the site's terms of service before you embark on anything like this.

Comment: @triplee - point well taken.  Thanks.